# How generate a list of consecutive month dates as a column in MariaDB

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I need to generate a list of consecutive month dates as a column in MariaDB, achieving the following:

| INDEX | MONTH |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | '2023-01-01' |
| 2 | '2023-02-01' |
| 3 | '2023-03-01' |
| 4 | '2023-04-01' |
| 5 | '2023-05-01' |
| 6 | '2023-06-01' |
| 7 | '2023-07-01' |
| 8 | '2023-08-01' |